# Unable to Commit Batch Uploads (No Error Script)

Tags: batch

Has anyone else had any issues with committing batch uploads into records?  There is no error message and the status remains in "processing for upwards of 24hrs".  The records I am trying to process are related to NGOC's "Giving" record type.

Comment: Hi K.Brown, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful. You might also want to look at your debug logs on this job to learn what, if anything they can tell you about it.